# code is correct but certain syntax not upgraded, how to crack

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
df["eps"]= df["price"]/ df["eps"]
```

showing as :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'

```
df["eps"]= df["price"]/ df["eps"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert them to float as follows:

```
df["eps"]= df["price"].astype(float)/ df["eps"].astype(float)
```